# Accessing JSONObject nested inside two JSONArrays

Tags: java, json

I'm trying create a calendar. I have a base "year" JSONArray containing twelve "month" JSONArrays each containing their corresponding amount of "day" JSONObjects. I made this using this code:

```
    int[] months = new int[] {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    //base json containing all 12 months and 365 days
    JSONArray calendar = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        calendar.put(new JSONArray());
    }
    //insert jsonobject into each month for corresponding amount of days
    for (int i = 0; i < calendar.length(); i++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < months[i]; y++) {
            ((JSONArray) calendar.get(i)).put(new JSONObject());
        }
    }
```

However, when trying to access a certain day JSONObject using this code:

```
    System.out.println(calendar.get(month).get(day);
```

I get this error:

```
    The method get(int) is undefined for the type Object
```

Any help help appreciated.

Comment: That's because `JSONArray` get method returns object type. you just have to cast it again before access `System.out.println(((JSONArray)calendar.get(month)).get(day);`

Comment: @lucid that fixed it thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, casting using this code:

```
    System.out.println(((JSONArray)calendar.get(month)).get(day);
```

works. However, you can also just use the getJSONArray() and getJSONObject() functions accordingly aswell to get around the issue.